# Footer navbar components align center in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wondering how can I align all components cenetered according to body page?

here is my code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login &middot; Leave System</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="divider vertical"><a href="">Company</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="">Education</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="">Consulting</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="">Projects</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="">Research</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="">Blogs</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

I tried something from my research. I found pull right or text align= centered. Nothing work he is my footer screenshot...

Or They can be only links. They must be align centered of course. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried the "text-center" class?

Or splitting the column into 3 col-xs classes with no content in the two outer cols?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a .container

```
<div class="container">
...
</div>
```